# TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined when using the react wrapper of chartjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm trying to use the react wrapper of chart.js and I'm having an issue.
When I'm trying to add a chart, there is an error ("
TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined")

The code is the following:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import api from '../../services/API';
import './Graph.css';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';

export default function Graph() {
    const [dataChart, setDataChart] = useState({ });

    useEffect(() => {
        const abortController = new AbortController();
        const signal = abortController.signal;
        const getData = async() => {
            let confirmedCases = [];
            let dateOfCases = [];
            await api.get('btt-prices', {signal: signal})
            .then ( resp => {
                for (const dataObj of resp.data ) {
                    console.log( dataObj )
                    confirmedCases.push(dataObj.price);
                    let tempDate = new Date (dataObj.date);
                    dateOfCases.push(tempDate.getUTCDate());
                }
            });
            
            setDataChart({ 
                labels: dateOfCases, 
                datasets: [{ 
                  label: 'Confirmed cases', 
                  data: confirmedCases 
                }]
            });
    
            //console.log(dataChart)
        }

        getData();
        return () => {
            abortController.abort();
        }
    }, []);
    
    return(
        <div className='container'>
            <Line data={ dataChart }/>
        </div>   
    );
}
```

The error that shows is the following:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/e/Desktop/test/front/node_modules/react-chartjs-2/es/index.js:643
  640 | }(_react["default"].Component);
  641 | 
  642 | exports.Scatter = Scatter;
> 643 | var defaults = _chart["default"].defaults;
  644 | exports.defaults = defaults;
```

I tried to search about it but I can't see any solution... I tried to install again chartjs (besides react-chartjs) just in case, but the error still remains.
How can I solve this error
Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Which version of chart.js are you running because if you reinstalled it its a high chance you are running version 3 of the lib which is at the moment still not compatible with the wrapper so you will have to install the latest version 2 release of chart.js (2.9.4)

Comment: You were totally right. You saved my day, thanks!!

Comment: I did face this problem when I did update my project dependencies from chart.js 2.9.3 and react-chartjs-2  2.9.0 to a newer chart.js version the solution is to downgrade  to chart.js 2.9.3

Answer (score 3):

Yes, thanks now this solution also work for me,

I was using chart.js with a version of >3.x

then I have downgrade the version to 2.9.4 then it worked for me.

Yarn Command


**yarn add react-chartjs-2


yarn add chart.js@2.9.4**

Answer (score -1):

First

```
npm uninstall react-chartjs
```

then

```
npm i react-chartjs-2@2.9.0
```